# Complex string manipulation in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to change the characters in a vector of strings from simple letter characters (species names, eg. `c("Struthio camelus",...,)`) to more complex expressions (eg.  `c('TS = "Struthio camelus"',...,)`) so this can be used to query the Web of Science for publications per species. Since I will have ~ 10000 species to query, I would like to identify a function that will convert these strings.

I have explored the `gsub()` function to achieve this, but `gsub()` doesn't support this kind of string manipulation.

Example:

```r
vector.a <- c("Struthio camelus", "Rhea americana", "Rhea pennata", "Casuarius casuarius")

vector.b <- c('TS = "Struthio camelus"', 'TS = "Rhea americana"', 'TS = "Rhea pennata"', 'TS = "Casuarius casuarius"')
```

Essentially, I want to convert `vector.a` to `vector.b` as the latter is in the correct format to query the Web of Science database. The single and double quotes are required as presented in vector.b because of the required formatting for the queries. Thus, the difficulty in manipulating the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To round out the answers, as well as to give an option which might scale better than `paste` should your replacement ever get more complex, we can try using `sub` here:

```
vector.a <- c("Struthio camelus", "Rhea americana", "Rhea pennata", "Casuarius casuarius")
vector.b <- sub("^(.*)$", "TS = \"\\1\"", vector.a)
vector.b

[1] "TS = \"Struthio camelus\""    "TS = \"Rhea americana\""     
[3] "TS = \"Rhea pennata\""        "TS = \"Casuarius casuarius\""
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `paste` from `base R`

```
vector.b1 <- paste0('TS = "', vector.a, '"')
identical(vector.b, vector.b1)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Benchmarks

```
test <- rep(vector.a, 1e6)
system.time(sub("^(.*)$", "TS = \"\\1\"", test))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.249   0.008   2.257 

system.time(paste0('TS = "', test, '"'))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.849   0.002   0.852
```